# Figure caption above figure

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
```{r fig1, fig.cap="This is a caption", fig.width=7, fig.height=5}  
x = 1:50
y = x^2
plot(x, y)
````

```

When I run this code in an R Markdown file, the figure caption is placed at the bottom of the figure.

How do you make the caption appear above the figure?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

````
```{r fig1, fig.width=7, fig.height=5,}  
x = 1:50
y = x^2
plot(x, y,main = "This is a caption")
```
````

Comment: That is the title for the plot though. I want to move the latex caption so that it is above the plot, instead of below the plot.